# Hide GET parameters in a URL / rewrite to a clean URL / save GET params in SESSION?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, get, session-cookies

I've looked around here but I can't find a matching solution to my problem here.

What I want to do is 1) clean up the URLs with GET params in them and 2) save those GET params in session variables.

This will also need to be done on all files on the site, so the GET params could get passed to any file on the server in any order.

So, for example, if one of the files is:

http://mydomain.com/page.php?a=1&b=2&c=3

and another is:

http://mydomain.com/anotherpage.php?b=2&a=1

I'd need those rewritten or redirected to /page.php and /anotherpage.php, respectively, while storing the GET params in session, so having $_SESSION['a'] = 1, etc.

I've managed to do this (kind of) by including a function called rewrite() in every file's header (before anything else) and going through all the variables in there, storing them in a session and then redirecting the file through header() to $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].

And it kinda works, but what I'm seeing now is issues with tracking scripts out there - when I try to integrate user tracking scripts I get errors because of a lot of redirects. Postbacks from other apps/websites are throwing 301/302 errors because of redirects as well.

So I was wondering is there a slicker method of just taking a QUERY_STRING for each called URL, storing all the key/value pairs from there in session cookies with key being the name of the session, value being the value of the session and just simply loading the clean SCRIPT_NAME instead without a possibility of endless redirection and all?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? What problem are you solving with this? Also, 301 and 3o2 are not errors but simple tell the user agent to look elsewhere.

Comment: well, the problem is all the GET parameters in the URL - I needed to hide those and clean the URL so it only shows the .php page called. As in, some of the parameters passed are dynamic prices and such, and I didn't want those showing up in the URL as visitors could easily figure out what they are and change them to suit their needs. Hence, what I do right now is grab the variables, store them in a session, redirect to the .php page without any variables in the URL and continue from there. But there's gotta be a better process for doing this as I am noticing some issues with infinite redirects

Comment: I would never put prices in the URL, even if you redirect away from it. It is just way too easy to temper with for people who know what they're doing. Instead I would generate 'tokens' in my database that indicate a discount on a certain product / products and then use such a token in the URL. That way people would have to guess for a correct token, which is a lot harder than just changing a price. As for the redirect loops, you would have to check how someone gets in a loop (use HTTP Live Headers in firefox for HTTP header inspection) and find a clever way to bail out at a certain point.

Comment: it's not the prices per-se, but product IDs and such, which pull different pricing from database. and there are other variables (not prices) that are being passed that we don't want users to be able to change but that don't warrant storing any sort of tokens in a database or encrypting/decrypting, so suggestion to store the GET params in a database as a token of some sort (or use database in any way) are not gonna help - it's a heavy traffic site and engaging database for something like this won't work.